# Babel –watch or webpack --watch does not work for me in the DOCKER/LXD container

Tags: docker, webpack, babeljs

I found an annoying issue:

If I change my code in the IDE and **babel** works in the container (like DOCKER or LXD) it ignores my changes from IDE.

For example

```
babel src/*.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch
```

On the other hand, it works properly if I make changes via an editor in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have this issue on Linux (Mac users do not have this issue).
The following solution works for babel and webpack:

**CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true** babel src/*.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch